# right-click-then-open-with works but simple left-click does not

Tags: google-drive-api

At some point in the last couple of days a bug seems to have materialised in my app's Google Drive integration, despite me not having changed anything, and usage remaining fairly constant.

When you left click one of the app's documents in Drive a new about:blank tab opens showing the app's icon and the text "Sorry, an error occurred while opening this file. Please try again. [XXXXX]" where [XXXXX] is a short string that seems to be different every time.  The create new works fine, and if you use the right-click menu and open with it also works fine.
All of this makes me think that there is a bug in the latest javascript update to Google Drive's main interface.

In terms of debugging, in the apiconsole the app has...

- The initiate oauth2 option unchecked
- The allow multiple files option unchecked
- Mobile browser support checked
- 24 mime-types, 61 primary extensions, and 1 secondary extension registered

Comment: It seems like there's a bug on our side that triggers when trying to open a file with a third-party app that is set as default app for that file type. The right-click workaround works correctly. We are investigating the issue and working on a fix, please bear with us a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a bug as Claudio has mentioned, I believe Google Drive SDK documentation needs to be updated too, since 'open' action is described only for "Open With" option:

https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open

I'm wondering how to trigger the proper action when registred mime-type can be managed by more than one installed application? Is there a way to set the default open action - or the application which created it will be used as the default? What's happen if you reach the application web by typing the url (not from UI Drive UI create action) and save the content on Drive, since you may be already authorized to do it?

Comment: It seems that Google Drive team has fixed it